# newly created columns from pivot_wider inside function cannot be accessed

Tags: r, function, pivot

I am trying to use pivot_wider inside a function. However, I cannot access the new columns once I have changed the format. I get the error message that columns a and b don't exist.

This is my function:

```
dip <- function(df, a, b, year_min) {
  
  wow <- df %>%  
  filter(country %in% c("a","b")) %>% 
  filter(date >= year_min) %>% 
  group_by(rcid) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "rcid", 
              names_from = c("a","b"), 
              values_from = "vote") %>% 
  na.omit()
  
  percentage <- sum(wow$a == wow$b)*100/nrow(wow_df)
  
  return(percentage)
}

dip(joined_df, "United States", "Germany", 1990-01-01)
```

When I try to run the code without the function, it works:

```
joined_df <- un_votes %>%
  inner_join(un_roll_calls, by = "rcid")
   
wow_df <- joined_df %>% 
  filter(country == "United States" | country == "Germany") %>% 
  filter(date >= "1990-01-01") %>% 
  group_by(rcid) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "rcid", 
              names_from = country, 
              values_from = "vote") %>% 
  na.omit()

percentage <- sum(wow_df$"Germany" == wow_df$"United States")*100/nrow(wow_df)
```

I am fairly new to function and appreciate any tips. The data I'm using is from the un_votes packages.

This is the error message I get:

> Error in `chr_as_locations()`: ! Can't subset columns that don't
> exist. ✖ Column `a` doesn't exist. Backtrace:
>
> 1. global dip(joined_df, "United States", "Germany", 1990 - 1 - 1)
> 2. tidyr:::pivot_wider.data.frame(...)
> 3. tidyr::build_wider_spec(...)
> 4. tidyselect::eval_select(enquo(names_from), data)
> 5. tidyselect:::eval_select_impl(...)
>    ...
> 6. tidyselect:::reduce_sels(node, data_mask, context_mask, init = init)
> 7. tidyselect:::walk_data_tree(new, data_mask, context_mask)
> 8. tidyselect:::as_indices_sel_impl(...)
> 9. tidyselect:::as_indices_impl(x, vars, call = call, strict = strict)
> 10. tidyselect:::chr_as_locations(x, vars, call = call)  Error in chr_as_locations(x, vars, call = call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we need to unquote the `"a"`, `"b"`.  In addition, replace the `$` with `[[`

```
dip <- function(df, a, b, year_min) {
  
  wow <- df %>%  
  filter(country %in% c(a, b)) %>% 
  filter(date >= as.Date(year_min)) %>%   
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "rcid", 
              names_from = country, 
              values_from = "vote") %>% 
  na.omit()
  
  percentage <- sum(wow[[a]] == wow[[b]])*100/nrow(wow)
  
  return(percentage)
}
```

-testing

```
dip(joined_df, "United States", "Germany", "1990-01-01")
[1] 33.33333
```

#### data

```
joined_df <- structure(list(rcid = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), country = c("United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Spain", "Spain", 
"Spain", "Spain", "Spain"), date = structure(c(12904, 8066, -25932, 
8401, 12843, 11231, 6971, 10470, 9251, 13787, 14304, 14396, 13361, 
11566, 8126), class = "Date"), vote = c(73, 88, 25, 73, 76, 73, 
91, 25, 88, 31, 45, 34, 80, 66, 60)), row.names = c(NA, -15L),
 class = "data.frame")
```